# Postgres: Query results not as expected?

Tags: postgresql, subquery, point-clouds

I have written in C and VB before but this is my first time with Prostgres. I have been working on my application for about a month but have come against a problem which has stumped me for around a week.

I have approx 7000 rows in a table called xyzfloats.  Each row contains 3 floats (x float,y float,z float) (pointcloud represention in meters)) There will be around 2.6 billion rows in the final version so I am trying to work with a subset to save time.

My other table, xyztable4, contains 24,000,000 rows. Each row is:
 xcell int, ycell int, points int, total float.

The first two ints contain an x,y index. I created this by using generate_series with a cross join

```
create table xyztable4(

xcell int,
   ycell int,
   points int default 0,
   total float default 0
)

insert into xyztable4 (xcell, ycell) 

select from generate_series(-1000,6000) as xcell cross join generate_series(-40,3360) as ycell;
```

The plan is that each x,y in the float table is placed into a small square with sides of 0.05m

When the correct square for x and y is identified the z is added to the 'total' column and the 'points' column is incremented.

Here is the code:

```
with subquery as (
     select x,y,z
     from xyzfloats)
update xyztable4
set
   points=points+1,
   total = total + subquery.z
from subquery

where xcell= floor(subquery.x/0.05) and ycell = floor(subquery.y/0.05)
```

I tried using cast but the index was wrong on the negative side.

Floor give the correct result.

The problem is that I only get 234 rows being processed not 7000.

I though it might be a problem with the precision of the numbers ie there may be some training digits that mean it is not exactly an int. I thought that postgres used an integer divide, like C?

It is always the same number of rows (234) that gets processed. It adds 1 to each of the points column. If I run the query again I get 2 in the points column. So it is consistently wrong.

I have tested this on small scale. (  9 rows of xyz's) and it works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

The query is not doing what you expect it to because of the way the `UPDATE ... FROM ...` works in postgres. Here's the quote from the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html):

> When a FROM clause is present, what essentially happens is that the target table is joined to the tables mentioned in the from_list, and each output row of the join represents an update operation for the target table. When using FROM you should ensure that the join produces at most one output row for each row to be modified. In other words, a target row shouldn't join to more than one row from the other table(s). If it does, then only one of the join rows will be used to update the target row, but which one will be used is not readily predictable.
>   
>   Because of this indeterminacy, referencing other tables only within sub-selects is safer, though often harder to read and slower than using a join.

You need to make sure that the join between the table you are updating (`xyztable4`) and the table in the `FROM` clause produces one row per row in the main table. You can do it like this:

```
with subquery as (
     select 
       floor(x/0.05) xcell,
       floor(y/0.05) ycell,
       count(z) cnt,
       sum(z) total_z
     from xyzfloats
     group by 1, 2
)
update xyztable4 
set
   points=points + subquery.cnt,
   total = total + subquery.total_z
from subquery

where xyztable4.xcell = subquery.xcell and xyztable4.ycell = subquery.ycell
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help and guidance. The 50mm squares are now being populated, but there is still only 234 rows being added to the xyztable4 from a possible 7000?

Comment: OH..DOH sorry the 7000 records have been done as there are now multiple entries in the boxes. Thanks again for all your help